# Replace within delimiters (N++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove all instances of a string, but only in text between square brackets.

So if the removed string is an ellipsis:

```
One ... Two ... Three [Four ... Five ... Six] ... Seven
```

Expected output:

```
One ... Two ... Three [Four Five Six] ... Seven
```

Shouldn't be too hard in RegEx, for preference in Notepad++?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by anchoring with [**`\G`**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G).

```
Find: (?:\G(?!^)|[^[]*\[)[^].]*\K\.+\h*
Replace:
```

`\G` can match at one of two positions; the start of the string position or the position at the end of the last match. The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included. You can see the below demo.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qR0mW5/3)

Answer (score 1):

The text of the string would be important to answer your question entirely fully, but overall here's what you're going to need....
*(shown in sublime with Regex on, but will work identically in Notepad++)

Find:

```
\[[^\]]*]
```

Replace: Replace with literally nothing to blank out anywhere the regular expression matches.

Breakdown Find:

1. [    - literal bracket
2. [^]]  - Anything not the right bracket
3. * - Any iteration of the "anything not the right bracket"
4. ] - The outside right bracket

Breakdown Replace:

1. Literal nothing, replaces everything inside the brackets with nothing at all

Thins to consider:

1. If you want to keep the brackets the replace the statement changes
2. You may need to consider your values separator character

Image to validate(Used sublime text for better highlighting):

[image: Working Regex as requested, but in SublimeText2]

Comment: Replaced Value:   Input: **One ... Two ... Three  ... Seven **

Answer (score 1):

```
\.{3}\s*(?=[^\[]*\])
```

You can simply use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/16